# Error regarding the use of lm() function (in R)

Tags: r, regression

I am still new to R and not very familiar with how the code works there. I want to do OLS regression but I don't understand why the following code does not work. Can someone tell me what I have done wrong please?

```
wage <- read.csv("wage21.csv")
earnings <- wage$EARNINGS    
S <- wage$S    
model1 <- lm(earnings  ̃ 1+S)
```

It responds with an error of

```
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:6:24: unexpected input
5: 
6: model1 <- lm(earnings  <cc>
                          ^
Traceback:
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It looks like you have some unusual character just before `1+S`.

Comment: You may try this : `formula(earnings ~ 1 + S)` inside `lm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fit1 <- lm(EARNINGS ~ 1+S, data = wage)
```

Comment: Note you don't need anything to do anything other than read.csv into the wage data.frame and then use that single line above.

Comment: also, the intercept is added by default